# webforms : add dynamically in javascript option to a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am developping an asp.net webforms application. My page is composed of 2 dropdown list.
At each selection on ddl1, I want to add dynamically via javascript the selected element of ddl1 to ddl2. By default when first loading the page, ddl1 is composed of 3 elements (a,b,c) and ddl2 is only composed of one element (a).

```
<script>
function ddl1_handler()
{
   var ddl2 = document.getElementById("ddl2");
   var newOption = document.createElement("option");
   newOption.text = document.getElementById("ddl1").value;
   newOption.value = document.getElementById("ddl1").value;
   ddl2.add(option);
}
</script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onChange="ddl1_handler()">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

This is my code_behind code :

```
private List<string> choices = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c"};

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   foreach (var choice in choices)
   {
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(ddl2.UniqueID, choice);
   }
   base.Render(writer);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!this.IsPostBack)
   {
      this.ddl1.Items.Clear();
      foreach (var choice in choices)
      {
        this.ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem(){ Text = choice, Value = choice}); 
      }

      this.ddl2.Items.Clear();
      this.ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem(){ Text = choices.First(), Value = choices.First()});
   }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var selectedValue = this.ddl2.selectedValue;

}
```

With the following code, when I first load my page, my ddl1 is composed of a,b,c and my ddl2 is composed of a. I then select b on my ddl1, this element is added to my ddl2. I select this element on my ddl2 and then click on my button. But when I arrive on my button1_click handler, my selected value is still a, i don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items inserted in client-side code are not persisted in code-behind. You could set up a [mechanism involving hidden fields](http://forums.asp.net/t/1275211.aspx?add%20items%20to%20a%20dropdown%20list%20using%20javascript%20) to get the value back but I think the easiest solution is to add the item in code-behind and use an UpdatePanel to avoid refreshing the whole page.

Here is how it could be used, showing how the update can be triggered by a control inside or outside of the panel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
...
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl3" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Since the property `ChildrenAsTriggers` of the UpdatePanel is true by default, a selection in `ddl1` will update the panel. On the other hand, `ddl3` will have a similar effect because it is registerd as a trigger of the UpdatePanel.

The following event handler could be used by both `ddl1` and `ddl3`:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    ListItem item = ddl.SelectedItem;
    ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value));
    ddl.Focus();
}
```

Please note that `ClientIDMode="Static"` has been removed since it does not mix well with UpdatePanels.

I included the ScriptManager declaration in the markup as a reminder, since it is required when using UpdatePanels.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am totally new to webforms and I just have one question, if I understand, I place my ddl1 in the updatePanel cause I want to trigger a postback without a full refresh, but why do I need to put the ddl2 in it also?

Comment: @user2443476 - In fact, it is the other way around: `ddl2` must be in the UpdatePanel in order to be updated without updating the whole page but `ddl1` could be outside of it and still trigger the update of `ddl2`. I modified my answer to show how it could be done with the control `ddl3`. Finally, to check if the UpdatePanel works, you can make this test: add a Label inside the UpdatePanel and another outside of it, and change their content in the `ddl_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. You will see that only the Label inside the panel is updated.

Comment: thank you for your help and for the clear explanation.

Comment: So I tried your solution, everything works. I just don't understand the use of ddl.focus. There is no difference with or without it.

Comment: You can comment out `ddl.Focus()` and see the difference of behavior between `ddl1` and `ddl2` after changing a selection. The difference is obvious in IE: the focus is clearly lost for `ddl1`. It is also noticeable in Chrome (by the focus contour) but not so visible in Firefox. The behavior, however, shows that the focus is lost in all browsers: after a selection in `ddl2`, you can open the list with Alt+Down or change the selection with the Down key. It doesn't work for `ddl1` unless you put the focus back with `ddl.Focus()` (or by clicking on the control).

Comment: ok thanks. I am experimenting a new problem but I think that I am going to do a new post. Supposing that ddl1 is a infragistics webdropdown, its event handler provides me the new selection object but it's not what it's actually selected, this is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967018/webforms-use-infragistics-webdropdown-in-updatepanel