# webforms : use infragistics webdropdown in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, infragistics

For your information (this was my original problem [webforms : add dynamically in javascript option to a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955982/webforms-add-dynamically-in-javascript-option-to-a-dropdownlist), solved thanks to ConnorsFan).

My goal is to having a infragistics dropdownlist enabling multi selection and at each selection I want an event fired server side without refreshing the whole page.

This is my aspx page :

```
<%@ Register assembly="Infragistics45.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.20161.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.ListControls" tagprefix="ig" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <ig:WebDropDown ID="WebDropDown1" runat="server" Width="200px" OnSelectionChanged="WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged" EnableMultipleSelection="true" EnableClosingDropDownOnSelect="false" AutoPostBack="true">
</ig:WebDropDown>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlId="WebDropDown1" EventName="SelectionChanged"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my code-behind page :

```
    private List<string> allPossiblechoices = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c","d","e" };

    private List<string> defaultChoices = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach(var choice in allPossiblechoices)
            {
                WebDropDown1.Items.Add(
                    new DropDownItem()
                    {
                        Text = choice,
                        Value = choice,
                        Selected = defaultChoices.Contains(choice)
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }

    protected void WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged(object sender, DropDownSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         // I put a breakpoint here to see what e.NewSelection and e.OldSelection are
    }
```

By default, when the page is requested for the first time, the dropdown is composed of a,b,c,d,e and only a,b,c are selected.

When I select d, a request is indeed send to the server (I put a breakpoint in my event handler) and the results are correct :

EventArgs e.OldSelection contains a,b,c.
EventArgs e.NewSelection contains a,b,c,d.

Then, I deselect d and the results are the following :

EventArgs e.OldSelection contains a,b,c.d.
EventArgs e.NewSelection contains a,b,c,d.

I don't understand why EventArgs e.NewSelection contains d even if I deselected it.

The fact that it's even more strange, is that I have done the same thing without the updatePanel and everything works fine, the selection (new and old) are correct.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try putting `WebDropDown1` inside the UpdatePanel?

Comment: I don't want to put it in because at each selection on the webdropdown1, it will be closed, and so the fact that doing a multi selection in one time will be lost (even with the attribute EnableClosingDropDownOnSelect)

Comment: According to the following article, the list will always close on postback: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/92484.aspx. Unless you re-open it every time with `openDropDown` (which will cause a flicker effect), you may need to implement the client-side code that you were considering at first in your other post. At the moment, the WebDropDown stays artificially open because it is not included in the partial update.

Comment: This other article gives a few references on how to add items in the WebDropDown, using client-code: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/90300.aspx.

Comment: ok thanks I am going to try but with this solution am I not coming to the original problem : elements added via javascript are not persisted when coming to server

Comment: Yes. Every time you add an item to the list, you could also append it to a hidden field value with a separator (e.g. `hiddenNewItems.value = 'New Item A|New Item D|New Item B"`). You would then have access to these new items in code-behind through the hidden field value.

Comment: FinallyI have put my 2 dropdown in the updatePanel, everything works well except that my webdropdown is closed at each selection on it. I was searching a solution : knowing that webdropdown.OpenDropDown allows me to open it on client side, I was wondering, is there any function or event in javascript allows me to execute a js code after every updatePanel and determines which element has provoked the updatePanel. If it's the case, I could execute WebDropDown.openDropDown after each updatePanel provoked by the selectedIndexChanged on WebDropDown. I tried the pageLoad event without success.

Comment: I will post an answer in a few minutes. It will not have been tested however (because I don't use Infragistics).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `RegisterStartupScript` static method of the ScriptManager class to add some Javascript code to be executed after the event handler has returned. In the code below, I assume that the ID of the UpdatePanel is `UpdatePanel1`.

```
protected void WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged(object sender, DropDownSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WebDropDown wdd = sender as WebDropDown;
    string scriptCode = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').openDropDown();", wdd.ClientID);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "WDDScript1", scriptCode, true);
}
```

If it works, you will probably see the WebDropDown closing/opening when the panel is updated (unfortunately).

Comment: The problem with this is that my code will be executed every time the update panel is refreshed. I want my js code to be executed only if it's the dropdown1 that has provoked the update panel refreshing, not for dropdown2,3 or any other control triggering the updatePanel refreshing.

Comment: You can put a condition in the common event handler: `if (sender == WebDropDown1) { // Run script stuff here }`. Otherwise, you can set `WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged` as the event handler for `WebDropDown1` and set another event handler for the other WebDropDown controls, putting some common code in a utility function.

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure if I clearly understand, does I need to put this in the client side or the server side.

Comment: It is on the server side. Before I add that piece of code to the sample, I would like to know: is the same event handler (`WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged`) attached to all your WebDropDowns? If so, is it necessary? If the event handler was attached only to the DropDown #1, you would know that the postback was triggered by that one.

Comment: No i have different handlers for different controls, so I need to know which one triggers the updatepanel refresh

Comment: If `WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged` is attached only to the DropDown #1, and if the call to `RegisterStartupScript` is only in that event handler, it will be executed only when that DropDown #1 triggers the postback. So there should be no problem. You can put a breakpoint in the event handler to check that it is called only when it is supposed to be.